# Handling security in an ASP MVC application that uses JS to a REST API

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, node.js, rest

I have an ASP MVC4 web site. Originally, most of the content was served via controllers as one would expect. I have moved the data storage from SQL Server to MongoDB. I have also added a lot of ajax to update data client side, without a full refresh. This is working fine, but my controllers now have *lots* of methods that take json and return json. I was able to build a Node.js server that hits the database and exposes exactly the same functionality, without lots of going to and from C#.

My javascript client-side is now calling a Node.js REST API, this works great. My 'secure' code (like adding a new user) hits the same REST API from the server side.

My question is this: How can I handle security properly with this? I have three scenarios:

1. GET api/messages: No need for security, I want to expose my site's messages to anyone who is interested via a Json REST API.
2. GET api/my/messages: I need to allow access to this only if the user is logged in (it gets the user's messages).
3. POST api/users: This is a function that should only be called from the server, and nothing else should be able to use it.

As the user is already logging in to my ASP website, how can I use their logged in credentials to authenticate them with my REST service? While the user is logged in, the pages client side will hit it regularly for updates.

Is there any sensible/standard way to do this? The core idea is that the client side code uses a REST API that is at least partially open to the public, and that in fact that API offers all of my business logic - only parts of it (like creating a user) are locked down to super-admins only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you still use the asp.net website for? Could you move it all over to Node.js?

Comment: @AndyD I will retire the ASP website in time with any luck, the issue is still that whatever I port it to, I need to secure the calls to the Node.js service that happen from the client-side - from the server side it's not a problem as I can access a private service.

Answer (score 2):

Create two authentication middleware handlers. One you add to all your "my" routes and another which you add to your POST routes.

The "my" authenticator takes the asp.net auth cookie that is present in the request and makes a http call to your asp.net mvc site with it.

You'll need an action which either returns a 401 if the cookie is invalid otherwise it returns some info about that user's permissions perhaps.

If the request into node doesn't have a cookie, return a 401 again.
In addition, to prevent excessive calls to your mvc site to check the cookie, you could use the cookiesession middleware to set a cookie on the client with a flag of authenticated. That will result in 2 cookies for your client, but that shouldn't be an issue. Just make the node one expire before the aspx one.

The POST authenticator middleware can use any shared secret you like between your node and mvc server. e.g. a special header in the request.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is required to login you can use [Authorize] on your controller actions. Autorization will be handled like any other webrequest.

Furthermore you might consider to add a key to your api requests which you can provide in the initial page load. A autorized user will have a GUID which he will sent with the api call. You can check if this key was issued by your app to a valid user.

Comment: I haven't explained the problem very well - previously all of my business logic was exposed via [Authorize] actions on the controllers, but now the business logic comes from the REST API, which I call (most of the time) directly from the client - so from the client I'm actually skipping out the MVC part altogether and calling it directly, and it's that call I want to secure!

Answer (score 0):

As you said all the secure calls already go through your MVC server code which in turn calls the Node.js code, am I right? Basically you need a way to block calls to this Node.js from other clients that are not your MVC code.

Thinking out loud, these are the ideas that pop into my mind:

1. Use SSL only between MVC and Node. You can set up client and server certificates so that the Node code will only respond after authentication (I don't know how Node handles SSL so you will need some documentation here
2. If you want, the Node server could also check the call origin and so you can filter based on IP and only allow IPs where your MVC code is sitting
3. Use an encrypted authentication token on the secure methods on the Node code. Again I'm not really a Node expert but I can imagine it has ways of decrypting a token, or you can simply base it on a random number with a common seed... If noone has access to your server code ideally noone should be able to guess this token. Again, SSL will help against traffic sniffing

I am quite sure that people will come up with other ideas. For me, the most basic thing is anyway ensure that the secure methods are only accessible through an SSL connection and on this connection you can exchange all the info (token, passwords, etc.) you desire.

Comment: In addition to using SSL, you need to make sure you authentication tokens are not accessible in the client through javascript. Therefor, a http only, secure cookie is the easiest solution.